# ca-certificates on a raspberry pi 3 - update-ca-certificates plots and error

Tags: ssl, raspberry-pi

Something went totally wrong with my Raspberry Pi 3.  I had to run `fsck.ext3`, but many packages got corrupted, such as python etc. Now, `ca-certificates` won't reinstall.  Whenever it runs `update-ca-certificates`, this is the output:

```
Setting up ca-certificates (20141019+deb8u4) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs... wc: error while loading shared libraries: xit: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package ca-certificates (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
```

It doesn't say which shared library is the problem.  How can I find out?

Any tips are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was /usr/bin/wc
i found that out after running "debsums -cs" .. so i reinstalled coreutils and everything that fixed it.